# get rid of a visual studio code parasite workspace

Tags: visual-studio-code

[image: Description]

I have a parasite workspace in my visual studio code environment which corresponds to the download directory of my system. As a consequence, anytime I open the download directory from within my firefox web browser, it opens visual studio code !.see image
how to get rid of this parasite workspace while keeping the directory.
I am under Xubuntu bionic

Comment: have you tried `File > Open Recent > More...` and click x near the folder you don't want

Comment: Yes I did it . It does remove it from the Open recent List but is does keep it as a workspace folder. I guess I would need to remove the folder from the workspace.

Comment: you don't mention you have a Multi Root Workspace. It is a simple text file you can edit with any editor and remove the directory you want, or use the context menu on the explorer tab

Comment: I have looked for the file .code-workspace but could not find it. It is not in the .vscode nor into the .vscode-cpptools. Also, under the explorer tab, I do  not find any command to remove this directory from the workspace. Any help would be welcome

Comment: why do you have a screenshot with the settings tab if this is not related to settings at all, it is confusing.Your title bar does not contain the text `(Workspace)` so you don't have a Multi Root Workspace. Is `Telechargement` your download directory. Describe in detail what you do and what happens. Most likely it is a Firefox or OS file association problem. VSC is lauched with this download directory as argument. What is the application in the window behind, is it also VSC?

Comment: I updated the screen capture. yes telechargements is my download directory. whenever I click on my download icno in firefox, I get the 2 screens as shown in the new picture. One of them is titled "welcome -untitled (workspace) -  Visual Studio Code and the other one is titled Welcome Telechargement Visual Studio Code. Whenever I clos One of the 2 windows, the second one also closes.

Comment: you have to find out what Firefox wants to do when you click the download icon. It wants to launch something for which there is a file association. You have to find out where that is configured in the Desktop or OS or Window Manager